# error wtih SSIS Package execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I imported an SSIS package that was created from a lower version using VS2015 so it was automatically upgraded. here is the code that runs the package:

```
                Process process = new Process();
                process.ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    errorBuilder.Append(e.Data);
                };
                //call this before process start
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn";

                process.StartInfo.FileName = "DTExec.exe";

                process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/File " + pkgLocation;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

                process.Start();
```

but i get the error:

```
Started:  2:32:00 PM
Error: 2016-06-27 14:32:00.81
   Code: 0xC001700A
   Source: 
   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
End Error
Error: 2016-06-27 14:32:00.83
   Code: 0xC0016020
   Source: 
   Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".
End Error
Error: 2016-06-27 14:32:00.86
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: LoadClaimsFilePDNew
   Description: Error loading value "<DTS:Property xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>" from node "DTS:Property".
End Error
```

i have already installed sql server data tools and other things that might resolve but i can't make it work. i have vs 2015 and sql server 2012

Comment: Problem might be this. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2014/09/30/ssis-error-when-deploying-from-vs-2013-to-ssisdb-in-sql-2012/ .You would have to try with VS2012. VS 2013 is used for SQL Server 2014, VS 2010/12 is used for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rollback your package using whatever source control you are using.

Then open the package, allow the project to be converted, and all will be OK.